# Is there a limit to how deep an HTML document or CSS tree can be?

Tags: html, css

I've been wondering this for a while, because I've got some pretty deep HTML structures going on. My points are these:

- Is there a maximum limit to the number of nesting levels for HTML?
- Likewise with CSS - I need to select stuff from the leaf nodes of the HTML DOM tree?
- Is it browser dependent?

Thanks for any help,

James

Comment: I would say no, but it's only a guess.  Have you encountered any problems yet?

Comment: I've been having some strange CSS behaviour and I couldn't work out why it wasn't working. Thinking about it, it can't be a nesting issue. Maybe with CSS nesting? I'm using LESS which might be causing the issues.

Comment: Oh. Looks like I was being all clever and using the wrong CSS selectors as usual. Problem solved! As for the OP, it was more out of curiosity than anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Neither the [XHTML 1.0](http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/) nor the [HTML 4.01](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/) specification defines a nesting limitation. HTML5 is not yet standardized, but the [working spec](http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/Overview.html) does not reference a limitation.

The [CSS 2](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/) spec similarly contains no limit.

Browser-based limitations may be an issue in the future, but I was unable to find any problem reports with modern browsers.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to look through the spec - very handy.

Answer (score 8):

I'm going to lean toward no limit that I'm aware of.  You should check this one out:  http://www.geeksaresexy.net/2009/09/01/a-hidden-gem-in-html/.  The site is nested deeply enough to recreate a skyline using font tags.

Comment: +1 for a good answer, +(ovar 9000) for that hilarious website xD Thanks very much.

Comment: @JamWaffles - No problem.  I always think back to that one when someone asks me a question about tag nesting.  It's the best example I've seen of how overboard you can go.  Remember to tag answers as correct if you found what you're looking for.  Thanks!

Comment: I've gone with George Cummins' answer as he has references to the HTML spec. Thanks for your input nonetheless though :-)

Answer (score 2):

I think you'll hit memory limitations before you hit any DOM restrictions (if any exist; I believe they don't).